# Can we install ros Hydro on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using ROS hydro and Gazebo in my research, and I want to install the newest version of Ubuntu 13.10. Do you think I might have any serious incompatibilty issues?

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91631/can-we-install-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-13.10/) by [mowahed](https://answers.ros.org/users/4645/mowahed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't have very good reasons to use 13.10, I'd recommend using something between 12.04 and 13.04. It's much nicer not to have to install everything from source.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no official Debian packages for Ubuntu Saucy (13.10) (see http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#hydro-medusa-apr-2013).

But you should be able to compile everything from source fairly easy. Eventually some system package names have changes and you need to figure them out manually or provide updated mapping for saucy back to the rosdep database (see https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml#L275) in order for `rosdep install` to work properly.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mentar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2076/mentar/) on 2013-11-06**:
Can't find any documentation on how to override the resdep database files, can you shed some light on how to do so? Thanks!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-11-06**:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep/ http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep/Tutorials http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep/Tutorials/Add%20new%20OS%20to%20rosdep.yaml